# Simple Linear Regression Error in updating cost function and Theta Parameters

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I wrote a piece code to make a simple linear regression model using Python. However, I am having trouble getting the correct cost function, and most importantly the correct theta parameters. The model is implemented from scratch and not using Scikit learn module. I have used Andrew NG's notes from his ML Coursera course to create the model. The correct values of theta are [[-3.630291] [1.166362]].

Would be really grateful if someone could offer their expertise, and point out what I'm doing wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Load The Dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv("Population vs Profit.txt",names=["Population" , 
"Profit"])
print (dataset.head())

col = len(dataset.columns)
x = dataset.iloc[:,:col-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,col-1].values

#Visualizing The Dataset
plt.scatter(x, y, color="red", marker="x", label="Profit")
plt.title("Population vs Profit")
plt.xlabel("Population")
plt.ylabel("Profit")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

#Preprocessing Data
dataset.insert(0,"x0",1)
col = len(dataset.columns)
x = dataset.iloc[:,:col-1].values
b = np.zeros(col-1)
m = len(y)
costlist = []
alpha = 0.001
iteration = 10000

#Defining Functions
def hypothesis(x,b,y):
    h = x.dot(b.T) - y
    return h

def cost(x,b,y,m):
    j = np.sum(hypothesis(x,b,y)**2)
    j = j/(2*m)
    return j

print (cost(x,b,y,m))

def gradient_descent(x,b,y,m,alpha):
    for i in range (iteration):
        h = hypothesis(x,b,y)
        product = np.sum(h.dot(x))
        b = b - ((alpha/m)*product)
        costlist.append(cost(x,b,y,m))

    return b,cost(x,b,y,m)

b , mincost = gradient_descent(x,b,y,m,alpha)
print (b , mincost)
print (cost(x,b,y,m))
plt.plot(b,color="green")
plt.show()
```

The dataset I'm using is the following text.

```
6.1101,17.592
5.5277,9.1302
8.5186,13.662
7.0032,11.854
5.8598,6.8233
8.3829,11.886
7.4764,4.3483
8.5781,12
6.4862,6.5987
5.0546,3.8166
5.7107,3.2522
14.164,15.505
5.734,3.1551
8.4084,7.2258
5.6407,0.71618
5.3794,3.5129
6.3654,5.3048
5.1301,0.56077
6.4296,3.6518
7.0708,5.3893
6.1891,3.1386
20.27,21.767
5.4901,4.263
6.3261,5.1875
5.5649,3.0825
18.945,22.638
12.828,13.501
10.957,7.0467
13.176,14.692
22.203,24.147
5.2524,-1.22
6.5894,5.9966
9.2482,12.134
5.8918,1.8495
8.2111,6.5426
7.9334,4.5623
8.0959,4.1164
5.6063,3.3928
12.836,10.117
6.3534,5.4974
5.4069,0.55657
6.8825,3.9115
11.708,5.3854
5.7737,2.4406
7.8247,6.7318
7.0931,1.0463
5.0702,5.1337
5.8014,1.844
11.7,8.0043
5.5416,1.0179
7.5402,6.7504
5.3077,1.8396
7.4239,4.2885
7.6031,4.9981
6.3328,1.4233
6.3589,-1.4211
6.2742,2.4756
5.6397,4.6042
9.3102,3.9624
9.4536,5.4141
8.8254,5.1694
5.1793,-0.74279
21.279,17.929
14.908,12.054
18.959,17.054
7.2182,4.8852
8.2951,5.7442
10.236,7.7754
5.4994,1.0173
20.341,20.992
10.136,6.6799
7.3345,4.0259
6.0062,1.2784
7.2259,3.3411
5.0269,-2.6807
6.5479,0.29678
7.5386,3.8845
5.0365,5.7014
10.274,6.7526
5.1077,2.0576
5.7292,0.47953
5.1884,0.20421
6.3557,0.67861
9.7687,7.5435
6.5159,5.3436
8.5172,4.2415
9.1802,6.7981
6.002,0.92695
5.5204,0.152
5.0594,2.8214
5.7077,1.8451
7.6366,4.2959
5.8707,7.2029
5.3054,1.9869
8.2934,0.14454
13.394,9.0551
5.4369,0.61705
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is with your "product".  It is currently a number when it should be a vector.  I was able to get the values `[-3.24044334  1.12719788]` by rerwitting your for-loop as follows:

```
def gradient_descent(x,b,y,m,alpha):
    for i in range (iteration):
        h = hypothesis(x,b,y)
        #product = np.sum(h.dot(x))
        xvalue = x[:,1]
        product = h.dot(xvalue)
        hsum = np.sum(h)
        b = b - ((alpha/m)* np.array([hsum , product]) )
        costlist.append(cost(x,b,y,m))

    return b,cost(x,b,y,m)
```

There's possibly another issue besides this as it doesn't converge to your answer.  You should make sure you are using the same alpha also.

Comment: Thanks a Million! I just check other forums, and your parameters could also be the best fit. Can you please explain the changes that you have made to my code. The formula for achieving gradient descent is [link](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*8Omixzi4P2mnqdsPwIR1GQ.png) and I'm not sure I understand your implementation. I removed the np.sum from my "product" and got the values [[-3.630291] [1.166362]] . However that doesn't make any sense when compared with the formula. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: `hsum` is the sum `h_b(x^(i)) - y^(i)` for all `i` and product is the same sum but with `x^(i)` multiplied.  To figure out why your modified code works you would have to check what `h.dot(x)` does when `h` is a vector and `x` is a Nx2 matrix (i'm not sure off the top of my head).

Comment: Okay! Thanks a million for your help!